# Applet. UnsatisfiedLinkError when loading native .dll

Tags: java, applet, jnlp, unsatisfiedlinkerror

I have an applet with `.jnlp` file, and I want to use native `.dll` inside applet. So I inserted native `.dll` in root of `.jar` and in jnlp-file file I added this line:

```
<nativelib href="MILIB0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar" main="true"/>
```

This worked fine before I made changes to my program (I refactored program). But now it doesn't. What can cause this crash? Where to look for problem?

Can this problem be related with certificates? I have trouble with them, but other restricted operations works fine (e.g. saving file on local file-system).

Error text:

```
java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Unable to load library 'mydlllib'
```

Comment: I doubt you can use native code unless you use a signed applet, the security risks would be too high.

Comment: @SJuan76 yes, my applet is signed (it confirms that I can save some files on client machine)

Comment: @SJuan76 I think, If I can't use native code in applet (due to broken certificate) I would get security exception, not `UnsatisfiedLinkError`

Comment: Can you share the code of how you load the lib, and the structure in which it is packed. If you try to load the lib manually using System.loadLibrary(), do you get the same exception? Also, do you download your native resource eagerly? Check this link for JNLP help, because unless you provide more information, code, jnlp file or something, it will be really hard to help you: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/guide/jws/developersguide/syntax.html

Comment: @baba lib loaded by third-party jar. I don't have sources.. Structure of jar is standard maven structure, and in root of jar located this `.dll` libs.

Comment: `<nativelib href="MILIB0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar" main="true"/>`  A `main(String[])` need to be in a Java class in a Jar referenced in a `jar` element.  Check the JNLP using [JaNeLA](http://pscode.org/janela/) &  correct any errors it identifies.